# How to create loop only through existing pairs in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have Data Frame like below:

```
t = pd.DataFrame()
t["value1"] = [10, 20]
t["value2"] = [1, 2]
```

How can I create loop which will go only through existing pairs of values so: 10 1 and 20 2, how to diallow loop to create non existing combinations like: 10 2 and 20 1 ?

i have loop like below, but as you can see it creates non existing cominations (10 2 and 20 1), how to modify this loop?:

```
val1 = t["value1"].unique().tolist()
val2 = t["value2"].unique().tolist()

    for v1 in val1:
        for v2 in val2:
            print(v1, v2)
```

Comment: something like this : ``list(zip(t.value1, t.value2))``

Comment: could you present full code of loop using your solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for v1, v2 in zip(t["value1"], t["value2"]):
    print(v1, v2)

10 1
20 2
```